# Knexfile.ts cannot use es module type of export

Tags: typescript, knex.js

```
// Update with your config settings.

module.exports = {

  development: {
    client: "sqlite3",
    connection: {
      filename: "./dev.sqlite3"
    }
  },

  staging: {
    client: "postgresql",
    connection: {
      database: "my_db",
      user: "username",
      password: "password"
    },
    pool: {
      min: 2,
      max: 10
    },
    migrations: {
      tableName: "knex_migrations"
    }
  },

  production: {
    client: "postgresql",
    connection: {
      database: "my_db",
      user: "username",
      password: "password"
    },
    pool: {
      min: 2,
      max: 10
    },
    migrations: {
      tableName: "knex_migrations"
    }
  }

};
```

Boilerplater file above provided by `knex init -x ts` uses commonjs type of export, where I would expect that es module type of export would work as well and it doesn't.

Is this mandatory or is there some other reason why es modules export cannot be used? I can use import just fine.

Comment: You can change this type of export, and run using `ts-node`

Comment: @felixmosh that's what I did,,, using es module export for ts, and using commonjs for compiled results.